# $\mathrm{Tor}(M/\mathrm{Tor}(M))=0$ for an $A$-module $M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, torsion-groups

**Definition.** Let $M$ be an $A$-module. Define $\mathrm{Tor}(M)=\{m \in M : \exists a \in A-\{0\}, am = 0 \}$).

> Show that the quotient module $M/\mathrm{Tor}(M)$ doesn't have a non-zero torsion element.

I think we have to show that $\mathrm{Tor}(M/\mathrm{Tor}(M))=0$. So, $r \bar{m} = r(m + \mathrm{Tor}(M))= rm + \mathrm{Tor}(M)=0$.

Here I know that $rm=0$, but how could I show that $m=0$ ($r \not= 0$)?

Comment: $A$ is a domain?

Comment: @Taj I've already told you, it seems you have some troubles to understand when a residue class is zero. For instance, $rm + \mathrm{Tor}(M)=0$ implies $rm\in\mathrm{Tor}(M)$, not $rm=0$. (Then there is $s\in A$, $s\ne0$, such that $(sr)m=0$. If $A$ is an integral domain you are done: $m\in\mathrm{Tor}(M)$ hence $\bar m=\bar 0$. But if $A$ is not an integral domain the product $sr$ can be zero.)

Answer (score 3):

Unless $A$ is an integral domain, this is false!

Set $A=M=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$. Then $t(M)=\{0,2\}$, and $M/t(M)\simeq\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. Now notice that $2\cdot 1=0$ in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

You should assume that $a · \bar{m} = 0$ and conclude $\bar{m} = 0$. So you have $a · m + \mathrm{Tor}(M) = 0$, i.e. $a · m ∈ \mathrm{Tor}(M)$, and you want $m ∈ \mathrm{Tor}(M)$. Is it clear now how to proceed?

Comment: That would make sense if the answer even contained the whole proof. The idea was to put the proof together with OP. Also, it is clear from your answer that being an integral domain is really needed.